# Entity Framework 4.1 Docs say Database.SetInitializer() is "get or set"?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, initializer

This page says that Database.SetInitializer() "Gets or sets the database initialization strategy":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

I am interested in GETTING the current initializtion strategy, but the method returns void, there is no parameter-less overload, and there is no overload with a ref or out parameter.  So I'm at a loss as to how to use this.  Am I missing something obvious or is this a typo?

... If it's a typo, any suggestions on how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a typo. There is no public method or property to get current initialization strategy.

Comment: This makes me sad.  I went to the MSDN page and filled out the feedback form.